# graph generation in csv file

Tags: php, csv, graph

I have generated a graph based on the user, stored in database. This graph is generating in a web page. But I am thinking to generate this graph to a csv file. But I don't know whether it is possible or not. If so, please help me out.

Comment: You can't create a graph in a csv, since this is raw data only. If you already have a graph, you might want to store it as a picture. Otherwise, you'll have to use some Excel API, to create a file containing a graph. How do you generate the web graph?

Comment: Yes, but you can generate simply CSV file with data for this graph and open it with Excel. You can do that with file_put_contents() function.

Comment: I think the author asked about text graph data. Because as I understand now this data outputed on the web-page and need to CSV. Then it's a text data, not a picture.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this PHP function [PHP file-put-contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)